# Unresolved reference in WiX

Tags: wix

I need to check for .NET Framework before installing. I've added this

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40" />
        <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again. Contact support at support@Swiftposter.com if you have further issues.">
            <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40]]>
        </Condition>
```

The start of the file contains

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
```

and on linking I get the error

> error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol
>   'Property:NETFRAMEWORK40' in section 'Product:*'.

Is there a specific place where I should insert these lines? I tried most places I can think of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should add reference to WixNetfxExtension.
2. Use the property NETFRAMEWORK40FULL instead.

Comment: I'd also like to add, if you are building manually using light.exe, you also need to add `-ext WixNetFxExtension` to your command line

Comment: How do I use this property? where to add it ? NETFRAMEWORK40FULL ?